# SignalR 2 with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

We are working on a VueJS application that needs to interact with a SignalR 2 application (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js, .NET Framework). All the examples that I can see for adding SignalR to  Vue are for the SignalR version for .NET Core.
Is it possible to use SignalR 2 (.NET Framework) with Vue? Or do we need to create a new SignalR app with .NET Core version.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SignalR 2 javascript is incompatible with VueJS. Current route to handle this is to make a regular API call to the server and the server can interact with SignalR.